# sql=update returns a successful message but no changes were made to db

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to update a database with the following code:

```
// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET FirstName='$FirstName', LastName='$LastName', >>>>Email='$Email' WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

// if successfully updated.
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

I get a successful message but the information was not changed.  I realize this code is open to hacking and I will address that but I want to get it to work first.

Comment: Do you really have `>>>>` in your code? That's not valid. Are you sure there's a row that matches `$id`?

Comment: Why is there a `>>>> email` on line 13?

Comment: I took out the >>>> It didn't help

Comment: Yes I'm sure there is a row that matches $id

Comment: code starts here:http://www.sussexwarrenhrma.org/list_records.php

Answer (score 0):

If there's no error and you got zero modified rows, it must mean that you either write the same information that's already there or no rows match the condition. So either you don't have a row with the given ID, or you're writing the same value for every field that's already in the record.

Comment: it is not the same information that is already in the table and it does match the condition.  I can't see what the problem is.  Very frustrating

Comment: Check for mysql_affected_rows() - what does it say? (other than "ring-ding-dingering") It should be nonzero if something really happened. mysql_query only returns false if there's a problem with the query itself.

Comment: The problem was that I was not defining the variables.  I added this:  $FirstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FirstName']);
$LastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['LastName']);
$Email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);

That made it work until I added more variables now I get an error message
$id = intval($_POST['id']);

Answer (score 0):

Remove `>>>>` code in your update statement.

```
UPDATE $tbl_name SET FirstName='$FirstName', LastName='$LastName',
Email='$Email' WHERE id='$id'"
```

Also Check whether the `$id` is existing in the table.

Comment: $id is in the table
I don't get any errors but nothing in the table changes

Comment: @user3144171 have you try the query directly in sql?